# Google cloud bucket static site not loading without cache

Tags: web, dns, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I'm hosting my personal website, ericdetjen.com, off a google cloud storage bucket. Everything works well initially, yet when I clear my cache my browser says that it "cannot to the server"

Any help would be much appreciated

it seems to work if I link it for some reason too. You can see here by clicking this link: [ericdetjen.com](https://ericdetjen.com)

[screenshot of safari error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI2gi.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please start by reading this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does the same thing happen from a different browser?

Comment: Yes sadly it happens on all browsers @MikeSchwartz